# How to deal with many shaders in a complex WebGL program?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, glsl, webgl

I know that there are two main ways shaders can be used in a WebGL application:

1. store them in HTML inside a `<script type="x-shader">` tag like this

```
  <script type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    in vec3 aVertexPosition;

    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
  </script>
```

2. have them as multiline string in javascript:

```
  var myshader = `#version 300 es
    precision mediump float;

    // Supplied vertex position attribute
    in vec3 aVertexPosition;

    void main(void) {
      // Set the position in clipspace coordinates
      gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }`;
```

I'm currently making a complex WebGL program, and I have a lot of shaders (both vertex and fragment). I used method 1 to store them initially, but the HTML script is getting too crowded now. I would like a more elegant method to store and use them with performance in mind.

Thank you

Comment: Another option is to store them in independent files and use XMLHttpRequest to load them.

Comment: Can you explain your project structure more? Is it an HTML file with some <script> tags or are you using a bundler like webpack? If you use webpack you can store your shaders as .glsl files and use a custom loader to import them when required. The added benefit is that you can use a syntax highlighter with this approach.

Comment: I'm not using webpack yet but that's interesting!! Thanks for the tip!